# The choice with by simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

There is a problem, I can't choose region.
I have three models, spot => city, city => region. In the model spot havent field region.

```
class Spot < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
end

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
end

= simple_form_for(@spot, :url => admin_spot_index_path) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.association :city, :collection => City.all, label: false
  #TODO
  Select region ??
```

How in simple form indicate selection region ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rails wrapper in simple_form like this:

```
= simple_form_for(@spot, :url => admin_spot_index_path) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.association :city, :collection => City.all, label: false
  = f.input :region do
    = f.select :region, Region.all.map { |r| [r.name, r.id] }, :prompt => "select Region"
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks.
this is not what need =)
In the model spot, not connected with the model of the region, and thus, I will have an error.
undefined method `region' for #<Spot:0x0000000551d3a8>

Comment: you want to save region_id in spot field. or what?